# Database Partitioning Newbie - Rudimentary Web Indexer running slow

Tags: sql-server, database, partitioning

This is a rudimentary web indexer.

I have 2 database tables:

domainList:

```
PK domainName
UI domainNumber
   status  ...  start, indexing, completed.
```

and

domainPages

```
PK pageNumber
FK domainNumber
   pageHTML
   pageTitle
```

I have several "indexer" servers that load the websites HTML and store it into the database.

The database as it gets bigger is now slowing down considerably.

```
INSERT INTO domainPages (domainNumber,domainPageHTML,domainPageTitle VALUES ('" & domainNumber & "',N'" & domainPageHTML & "',N'" & domainPageTitle & "')")
```

This is taking a long time as there are many rows.  Reading from the table is taking a long time too.

I could create a new table for each set of domainPages, but I'd rather try something new: I'm looking at database partitioning to help.

All the examples on the 'net about partitioning use a date field,  whearas here I need to partition on the domainNumber in the domainPages table (which is a logical foreign key on the domainList - as I believe an actualy relationship will fail with partitioning).

So I think I'm looking at a partition per unique domain?  If that is correct how would I do this?  Are there any examples online that don't involve a date field, but a logical foreign key on a table.

Comment: Have you tried any indexing (before you partition)?

Comment: @astander Yes. Non-clustered on domainNumber

Answer (score 0):

I had no answers to this question, so I had to use separate tables for each domain.  Which means it takes a while to browse all the tables!

I did spot this however http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/25/sql-server-2005-database-table-partitioning-tutorial-how-to-horizontal-partition-database-table/  which is what I would have needed.  It is there for anyone else looking in future.

I've not tried it but I assume that for higher IDs you would run another function e.g. once IDs reach 500 like in this example:

```
  --Determine where values live before new partition
SELECT $PARTITION.Left_Partition (501)  --should return a value of 4

--Create new partition
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION Left_Partition ()
SPLIT RANGE(500)

--Determine where values live after new partition
SELECT $PARTITION.Left_Partition (501)  --should return a value of 5
```

According to [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/2007.03.partitioning.aspx) see section:  *Consider the table created in Figure 2. You can add a new partition to this table to contain values greater than 500, like this.*

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/2007.03.partitioning.aspx